# Outbound NAT on Windows

Tags: windows, nat, netsh

I am starting to admin Windows server and have some troubles with network tools.

I am trying to configure nat **on Windows Server 2012**.

My Windows VM has two networks adapters, the first one connected to my private network with the settings `10.38.1.1/26`. The second one is a virtual loopback with the settings `10.12.1.1/32`.

The first one is used for all the communication and the second one is used only to host my application (wich listening on `10.12.12.1:30001` and can't change it).

The network `10.12.X.X` must stay local on the VM and should not be seen from the network. So I want to NAT all the outbound traffic comming from my local application `10.12.1.1` to another application host on `10.38.1.2:30002`

I already did something similar on linux with this **iptables rule** :

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -o eth1 -d 10.12.1.2 -p tcp --dport 30002 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.38.1.2:30002
```

How can I do that with netsh ?

Comment: you can take a look : netsh interface portproxy (port forwarding)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already use portproxy to redirect incoming packets from my first network adapter to the virtual network adapter and it works. But the tool seems not build for outbound redirect.